# MySQL Create column that limits the amount of occurences of values

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I am currently developing an architecture in PHP and MySQL and a problem has arisen. I hope this isn't a ridiculous question but it would be very helpful if there was an answer.

The following is a simplified version of the actual situation. Lets say I have a table with 3 columns representing a number of locations. Each location can potentially be a default location:

```
location_id int(20), location_name varchar(255), is_default BOOL
```

Column `is_default` should only have the values true (1) or false (0). In addition I want to make sure that no more than one row can have is_default set to true. In other words I want to permit a maximum of one true value and a boundless amount of false values:

```
+-------------+---------------+------------+
| location_id | location_name | is_default |
+-------------+---------------+------------+
|1            |'England'      |1           |
|2            |'America'      |0           |
|3            |'China'        |0           |
|4            |'Russia'       |0           |
+-------------+---------------+------------+
```

The idea is that only one location can be the default location. Is there any way of expressing this as a data type or column attribute of some sort? Or would I have to enforce the rule in php by simply running two queries so that whenever a location is added whose is_default column = true the old default location's is_default column = false? It would be great if there was a way to enforce it in MySQL.

It seems like such a simple problem that I thought it would be common but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere on the internet including the MySQL reference. Unless there is some obvious database design flaw which I have managed to overlook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have another table where it belongs, I would create a separate table to specify the default like:

```
default_location table
+------------+
|location_id |
+------------+
|1           |
+------------+
```

This way, you can only have one.

Maybe this belongs in a settings table?

Comment: Yeah but he still can add another row to `default_location` table and he will have 2 default locations. Better way would be two update queries: `UPDATE location SET is_default = 0`, `UPDATE location SET is_default = 1 WHERE location_id = 1`

Comment: @piotrekkr, thanks for the input. It's true that another row can be added to create another default. That's one of the strengths of this method. Note that this is just an example. This column could very well be part of a user table, so each user could have their own default, or a system table, where each system has its own default, etc.

Comment: Nothing'd stop 2+ locations being set as default in the original table setup either. The sub-table method does at least save a bit of storage by not having this "pointless" field attached to ALL cities.

Comment: I like this approach as well but it still requires an insert and an update.  Not sure how important that is to the OP.

Comment: And also, if this is to be in a config/settings table (as suggested by @Ami), there can only be one.  ConfigId, ConfigName, ConfigValue... PK on ConfigName (sort of like a registry table)

Answer (score 1):

If all except one are 0, I would have a configuration file that defines the default value and get rid of the column in the table:

```
default_location_id = 1
```

Comment: +1 or a 'default_location' row in a `configuration_settings` table, or something; in short, wherever your config settings are.